# Cucumber - "You don't have a 'features' directory. Please create one to get started" message

Tags: ruby, cucumber

i'm learning cucumber and i'm having some issues. 
I created a feature into this location /Documents/calculator/features/adding.features

And when i execute "cucumber" in the /features folder, i get the following error/warning:

```
me@my-pc:~/Documents/calculator/features$ cucumber
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/ast/feature_element.rb:52: warning: circular argument reference - name
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
From:
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core_ext/disable_mini_and_test_unit_autorun.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:21:in `initialize'
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:40:in `new'
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:40:in `execute!'
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.3/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
You don't have a 'features' directory.  Please create one to get started.
See http://cukes.info/ for more information.
```

But if i manually put the feature path, it works(although the warning doesn't go away)

```
 me@my-pc:~/Documents/calculator/features$ cucumber ~/Documents/calculator/features/adding.features
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/ast/feature_element.rb:52: warning: circular argument reference - name
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
From:
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core_ext/disable_mini_and_test_unit_autorun.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:21:in `initialize'
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:40:in `new'
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:40:in `execute!'
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.3/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
Feature: Adding

  Screnario: Add two numbers
  Given the input "2+2"
  When the calculator is run 
  Then the output should be "4"

0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s
```

Anyone knows what is going on ?

Comment: It looks like an issue about your runner class. Can you please share it with us?

Comment: where can i find it ?

Comment: run cucumber from the calculator folder, then it can find features

Answer (score 0):

> And when i execute "cucumber" in the /features folder

Cucumber needs to be run from the root of your automation suite. In your case, the root is `~/Documents/calculator`

Steps:

1. `cd ~/Documents/calculator`
2. `cucumber features`

Try this [link](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/) for a quick tutorial to get started with Cucumber

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I created a 'features' folder at the root of my application and put my features file into it. Run 'cucumber' again and it found the features folder I just created.